# Remove duplicate row from output table

Tags: php, sql, inner-join, html-table

I want to remove the duplicate output in my table, the table looks like this

```
Order No  Customer Name  Order
1001       John          Milk
1001       John          Egg
1002       Mark          Milk
1002       Mark          Bread
```

I want it to be like this

```
Order No  Customer Name  Order
1001       John          Milk
                         Egg
1002       Mark          Milk
                         Bread
```

The order no and customer name uses rowspan = 2

Customer and Order comes from different table in my database

The query of this table comes from an inner join query join the two

```
$query = mysql_query("select customer.customerName, order.orderNo, order.item 
from customer inner join orderInfo on orderInfo.customerId = customer.customerId");

while($order = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 echo '<tr>
  <td>'.$order['orderNo'].'</td>
  <td>'.$order['customerName'].'</td>
  <td>'.$order['item'].'</td>
 </tr>';
}
```

and the output of the above code is the 1st illustration

How would I achieve the 2nd illustration, is there something wrong with my table relationship or should I use the right query?

Comment: That's not a dbms thing to do. Let the layer above take care of the presentation.

Comment: Can you add your PHP code?

Comment: @DesignerGuy done editing

Comment: @CodingCracker If I use the distinct, how would the two item with the same order no be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better of using group_concat:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    customer.customerId, customer.customerName, order.orderNo, group_concat(order.item SEPARATOR ',') as order_items
FROM 
    customer
INNER JOIN
    orderInfo on orderInfo.customerId = customer.customerId
GROUP BY customer.customerId
");
```

And in your code, just replace the separator:

```
while($order = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 echo '<tr>
  <td>'.$order['orderNo'].'</td>
  <td>'.$order['customerName'].'</td>
  <td>'.str_replace(',','<br/>',$order['item']).'</td>
 </tr>';
}
```

You won't need rowspan=2 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As jarlh told, its not a dbms thing too do, edit the query with order by order no and use the below code for your 2nd illustration

```
$previous=-1000;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
{
if($previous!=$row['orderNo'])
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['orderNo']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['customerName']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['item']."</td>";
}
else
{
echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>".$row['item']."</td>";
}
$previous=$row['orderNo'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not dynamic you can use following:

```
DECLARE @varTable TABLE (OrderNo NVARCHAR(10), CustomerName NVARCHAR(60), Order NVARCHAR(60))

INSERT INTO @varTable VALUES( CAST(1001 AS NVARCHAR(10)),   'John', 'Milk')
INSERT INTO @varTable VALUES( '',                           '',     'Egg')
INSERT INTO @varTable VALUES( CAST(1002 AS NVARCHAR(10)),   'Mark', 'Milk')
INSERT INTO @varTable VALUES( '',                           '',     'Bread')

SELECT * FROM @varTable
```

Answer (score 0):

check this query:

```
Select Dep, Case
             When rn = 1 And c_d > 1 Then
              d
             When c_d = 1 Then
              d
             Else
              Null
           End D1,
           Case
             When rn = 1 And c_k > 1 Then
              k
             When c_k = 1 Then
              k
             Else
              Null
           End K1,
           Case
             When rn = 1 And c_m > 1 Then
              m
             When c_m = 1 Then
              m
             Else
              Null
           End M1
      From (Select Count(1) Over(Partition By d,dep Order By d) c_d,
                   Count(1) Over(Partition By k,dep Order By k) c_k,
                   Count(1) Over(Partition By m,dep Order By m) c_m,
                   row_number() Over(Partition By dep Order By dep)rn,
                   d,
                   k,
                   m,
                   Dep
              From (Select 'ali' d, '1000' k, 'M' m, 'x' Dep
                      From Dual
                    Union
                    Select 'ali' d, '1000' k, 'H' m, 'x' Dep
                      From Dual
                    Union
                    Select 'ali' d, '1001' k, 'M' m, 'y' Dep
                      From Dual
                    Union
                    Select 'ali' d, '1000' k, 'H' m, 'y' Dep
                      From Dual))
```